# Use quotactl system call inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, system-calls

I want to use XFS filesystem quotas inside a docker container to limit the size of some directories. I already put quotactl in the seccomp whitelist (I am fully aware that this is not secure), but now I get a no such file or directory error.

The XFS filesystem is just accessible by a bind mount, so I tried using both the storage device from the host and from the container for the system call (for example `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5`), neither of them worked. The exact same program works perfectly fine on the host system.

Edit:
This is was strace tells me:

```
# On host system
quotactl(QCMD(Q_XSETQLIM, PRJQUOTA), "/dev/sda5", 0, {d_version=1, d_flags=XFS_PROJ_QUOTA, d_fieldmask=0x8, d_id=0, d_blk_hardlimit=20480, d_blk_softlimit=0, d_ino_hardlimit=0, d_ino_softlimit=0, d_bcount=0, d_icount=0, d_itimer=0, d_btimer=0, d_iwarns=0, d_bwarns=0, d_rtb_hardlimit=0, d_rtb_softlimit=0, d_rtbcount=0, d_rtbtimer=0, d_rtbwarns=0}) = 0
# Inside container
quotactl(QCMD(Q_XSETQLIM, PRJQUOTA), "/dev/sda5", 0, {d_version=1, d_flags=XFS_PROJ_QUOTA, d_fieldmask=0x8, d_id=0, d_blk_hardlimit=20480, d_blk_softlimit=0, d_ino_hardlimit=0, d_ino_softlimit=0, d_bcount=0, d_icount=0, d_itimer=0, d_btimer=0, d_iwarns=0, d_bwarns=0, d_rtb_hardlimit=0, d_rtb_softlimit=0, d_rtbcount=0, d_rtbtimer=0, d_rtbwarns=0}) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Is `/dev/sda5` existing inside the container?

Comment: That's what i forgot to check, I am rather new to docker. I assumed it was actually there because programs like df told me so.
Thank you

Comment: Well now I got around the problem by using --device with docker run, but now I get the "Operation not permitted" error. Is it possible to solve this too?

Comment: I think for `qoutactl` you just need to be root, ca't find any capabilities that are needed by it. It will be hard within docker..., try running with  `--privileged` or granting ` --cap-add SYS_ADMIN`

Comment: Just found the reason in the Linux source: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/quota/quota.c#L43
--privileged did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

With some help from the comments I was able to solve this problem, there are three things you need to do in order to use `quotactl` inside a docker container:

- Use your own seccomp configuration for the container and whitelist the `quotactl` system call
- Add the device to the container with the command line option `--device=/dev/sdXX:/dev/sdXX`
- Run the container in privileged mode with `--privileged`

Comment: Well, feel free to accept your answer, so this will not be left unaccepted. Also you may interest yourself in [how does reputation work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) ; )